# UDP Invalid Argument on Docker Swarm EC2

Tags: python, linux, docker, amazon-ec2, udp

When sending UDP packets on EC2 with Docker I sometimes get this strange error (not all messages sent have an exception) which never happens on our inhouse cluster using OpenNebula. I have allowed all inbound/outbound traffic on every port on all my EC2 instances. Here is the exception:

```
2017-01-19 10:01:53,170 - ERROR: Exception caught for address: 10.99.0.153
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./server.py", line 56, in <module>
    sock.sendto(bytes('{}'.format(i), "utf-8"), (address, PORT))
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I run 5 c4.xlarge instances with Ubuntu server 16.04 and Docker 1.12.6. They are all in the same docker swarm.

I create a service and a network subnet using the overlay driver. This service has a mount point to get the logs from each peer. I run 150 peers each having a memory limit of 300MB.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:jessie

RUN echo 'deb http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/debian/ jessie-backports main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    apt-get -yqq update && \
    apt-get -yqq dist-upgrade && \
    apt-get -yqq install --no-install-recommends dnsutils wget curl ntp python3 && \
    apt-get -yqq clean
CMD ["/opt/epto/container-start-script.sh"]
```

I use the following shell script as my CMD:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
MY_IP_ADDR=$(/bin/hostname -i)
MY_IP_ADDR=($MY_IP_ADDR)
./server.py ${MY_IP_ADDR[0]}
```

And this is the actual python script running:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import socketserver
import sys
import logging
import threading
import urllib.request
import time
import socket
from random import randint

PORT = 15342


class MyUDPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
    This class works similar to the TCP handler class, except that
    self.request consists of a pair of data and client socket, and since
    there is no connection the client address must be given explicitly
    when sending data back via sendto().
    """

    def handle(self):
        data = self.request[0].strip().decode("utf-8")
        logging.info("Message received from {} during loop {}".format(self.client_address[0], data))


class ThreadedUDPServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, socketserver.UDPServer):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST = sys.argv[1]
    logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s', level=logging.INFO,
                        filename='/data/{}.test'.format(HOST))
    server = ThreadedUDPServer((HOST, PORT), MyUDPHandler)
    server.allow_reuse_address = True
    logging.info("Create server listening on {}:{}".format(HOST, PORT))
    logging.info("Server allow_reuse_address: {}".format(server.allow_reuse_address))
    server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
    server_thread.daemon = True
    server_thread.start()
    sleep_delay = randint(10, 180)
    logging.info("Sleeping for {}s".format(sleep_delay))
    time.sleep(sleep_delay)
    logging.info("Finished sleeping")
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    content = urllib.request.urlopen('http://epto-tracker:4321/REST/v1/admin/get_view').read()
    content = content.decode("utf-8")
    addresses = content.split('|')
    logging.info("View size: {}".format(len(addresses)))
    i = 0
    while True:
        logging.info("Loop {}".format(i))
        for address in addresses:
            try:
                logging.info("Sending to {}".format(address))
                sock.sendto(bytes('{}'.format(i), "utf-8"), (address, PORT))
            except:
                logging.exception("Exception caught for address: {}".format(address))
        time.sleep(5)
        i += 1
```

I create a second service on the same overlay network. This one contains the tracker, which nodes will contact to obtain the network view:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.5.2-alpine

RUN pip install pydevd

COPY tracker.py /code/
WORKDIR /code

EXPOSE 4321

CMD [ "python", "./tracker.py" ]
```

the code file:

```
# import pydevd
import random
import logging


import time
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler

available_peers = {}
K = 25
logging.basicConfig(format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)


def florida_string(ip):
    available_peers[ip] = int(time.time())

    to_choose = list(available_peers.keys())
    logging.info("View size: {:d}".format(len(to_choose)))
    to_choose.remove(ip)
    if len(to_choose) > K:
        to_send = random.sample(to_choose, K)
    else:
        to_send = to_choose

    return '|'.join(to_choose).encode()


class FloridaHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/REST/v1/admin/get_view':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/plain")
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(florida_string(self.client_address[0]))
        elif self.path == '/terminate':
            if self.client_address[0] in available_peers:
                del available_peers[self.client_address[0]]
                logging.info("Removed {:s}".format(self.client_address[0]))
                logging.info("View size: {:d}".format(len(available_peers)))
            else:
                logging.error("IP already removed or was never here")
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/plain")
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(b"Success")
        else:
            self.send_response(404)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/plain")
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(b"Nothing here, content is at /REST/v1/admin/get_view\n")


class FloridaServer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.server = HTTPServer(('', 4321), FloridaHandler)
        self.server.serve_forever()


FloridaServer()
```

Has anyone experienced this same error on EC2 ?

Comment: Does this seem relevant: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/26019?

Comment: @void This does indeed seems relevant, thanks for pointing this issue, I never found it.

Comment: Can you try to increase [kernel buffer sizes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#/configure-namespaced-kernel-parameters-sysctls-at-runtime)?  For example, `net.core.wmem_default=131072`, `net.core.wmem_max=8388608`.

Comment: When reporting to docker upstream be aware that your code contains an error: `socket.sendto()` does not guarantee that all data will be sent, but instead [returns a number of bytes sent](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendto) and relies that sending side implements proper buffering. That can produce application-level errors not related to the main problem.

Comment: `sock.sendto(bytes('{}'.format(i), "utf-8"), (address, PORT))` why use udp if you slow down a socket connection(bad idea in-line method under for iterator).  Another point _how will be sure resource is available ?_ , did you have any flag for sending packet rapidly ? One way packet delay is minimum 50 microseconds(PC To PC, and on my device) , how know packet accepting  is successful ? Don't use UDP socket if haven't information of device capabilities.

Comment: @dsgdfg This is only a quick scenario pulled together showcasing the problem I experience in a real project which is not using python.

Comment: @Sekh Did you play with network buffer sizes? My guess is: docker -> isolated network namespace -> known problems with [limits](https://residentsummer.github.io/posts/2016/02/07/docker-somaxconn/) -> EINVAL might just screen another error -> high load -> buffers.

Comment: @void, yes it did not fix the problem unfortunately :/

Comment: Best things of playing real time data on over ethernet : "Need use pure Socket(not additional modules etc.)" . You missed UDP rules, udp services used 2 port(for bidirectional), so sending port and received port. **You can't connect to UDP server like HTTP_Server**  Please try: `import socket; print help(socket)`